# nyc coverage shows incorrect line numbers

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, istanbul, ava

My group is building an application with the following front-end stack:

- VueJS
- Webpack 2.2
- AvaJS (for unit testing)
- nyc (Istanbul) for test coverage

We started off with `vue-cli` to create a Webpack template for our project. For the most part everything has gone smoothly. We are able to use Ava for unit testing separate *.vue* component files using *vue-node* However there is a problem with the test coverage report generated through *nyc*. Below is a snippet of our *package.json* file with the relevant nyc and ava sections defined:

```
"nyc": {
    "exclude": [
        "build",
        "config",
        "static",
        "tests"
    ],
    "extension": [
        ".js",
        ".vue"
    ]
},
"ava": {
    "require": [
        "./tests/unit/helpers/setup.js",
        "ignore-styles"
    ]
},
```

All the tests pass successfully. The `nyc` report shows the following:
[image: nyc generated report]

The problem is that the line #s listed under *Uncovered Lines* don't exist. The *.vue* file is only 402 lines long so I can't figure out where these line #s in the nyc report are coming from.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you got [source maps](https://github.com/avajs/ava#code-coverage) set up?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah I saw that but don't quite know how to do that. I also didn't realize before that it was necessary I guess. Is it simply a matter of setting sourceMaps: true in nyc config in package.json? Because I did try that and no luck.

Comment: All I know about it I read right there: Make sure that the code you're testing includes an inline source map or references a source map file. If you use `babel-register` you can set the `sourceMaps` option in your Babel config to `inline`.

Comment: Got it. Yeah I'm still stumped. Unable to figure out how to integrate the sourcemaps option into my current config. Nothing so far as worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, you need to install `babel-plugin-istanbul` that instruments your code with Istanbul coverage. This plugin is in charge to get the right `sourceMap` for your code. So you need to disable instrument and `sourceMap` from `nyc`.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-istanbul
```

In the `.babelrc` file (generally found in the root folder of your project,) add the following so it only gets used by your test environment:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "istanbul" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then disable instrument and `sourceMap` from `nyc`. `babel-plugin-istanbul` will take care of it. And replace your `"require": "nyc"` with `"require": "babel-register"`.

```
"nyc": {
  "exclude": [
    "build",
    "config",
    "static",
    "tests"
  ],
  "extension": [
    ".js",
    ".vue"
  ],
  "require": [
    "./tests/unit/helpers/setup.js",
    "ignore-styles",
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "sourceMap": false,
  "instrument": false
},
```

Now you should be able to get coverage with `nyc`.

```
NODE_ENV=test nyc ava
```

*Sources:*

1. *https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-istanbul*
2. *https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#use-with-babel-plugin-istanbul-for-babel-support*

Comment: Excellent. My `nyc ...` command worked just fine except for the line numbers that were all completely off. Adding the Babel plugin for Istanbul and make sure the `"sourceMap"` and `"instrument"` were off in `nyc` did the trick.

Comment: _Cannot find module 'babel-register'_  is there some other dependency needed?